# How to rewrite a subfolder in the URL to a PHP get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making a webpage that uses one template HTML page and uses PHP to fill in the rest from JSON files.

I am trying to find out how I can rewrite a URL from `.../project/jsonfilename/` to `.../project/index.php?f=jsonfilename`.

I have tried to use the following code in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^project\/([^\/]+)\/?  /index.php?f=$1
```

But this passes "index.php" as the argument instead of the subfolder I want.

Comment: You RewriteRule is actally correct and does what you want to achieve - the URL `http://example.org/project/jsonfilename/` is rewritten to `http://example.org/index.php?f=jsonfilename` - isn't that what you want it to do? You can also try [this tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to test this out.

Comment: You said you wanted to rewrite this to `/project/index.php?f=jsonfilename`, but your shown rule redirects to `/index.php?f=$1`. (And if you had this .htaccess inside the `project` folder already, then the RewriteRule should not match either.) Now which one of the two is it, actually? // You probably need a RewriteCond that checks if the current request was not for `index.php` already, because currently you seem to have created a “loop” in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule in your .htaccess file (for /project/jsonfilename/ <> /project/index.php?f=jsonfilename)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^project\/(.*)\/$ /project/index.php?f=$1 [L]
```